# What does the Mystery button do?

Tags: lil-dungeon

In the iOS game Lil' Dungeon, on the menu screen, there is a button labelled "Mystery".

It is greyed out for me right now, but I am curious. How do I use it? What does it do?

Comment: o boy. thats almost as bad as a button labeled 'Dont press me."